# 1366, "Incorrect string value:

Tags: mysql, django, unicode

I have DB with charset *latin-1*.

When I'm getting some data from user, i encrypt it by **pycrypto**. 
It returns some strange string (for example, ��w0o4�Bd�), which is decoded by *latin-1 as* well.

When I try to write it in my DB, I'm getting error:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD\xEF\xBF\xBD...' for column 'access_key' at row 1
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: The output of encryption is usually binary data, so not text or anything that can be represented as text.  If that's the case store in as binary data in a varbinary column or encode it to text via base64.

Comment: @AlexK., type(my_encrypted_data) returns 'str'

Comment: Stupid me, you were right about base64! Thank you! P. S i don't know why but i can't mark your answer :(